# onpopstate event doesn't trigger in Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, safari, jquery-events

Chrome and Safari doesn't trigger the HTML5 `onpopstate` event.
Here is my example:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title></title> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
        <script> 
            window.onpopstate = function(e) {
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "HELLO";
            }
            $(function() {
                $("a").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.history.pushState({page: $(this).index()}, $(this).html(), $(this).attr('href'));
                });
            });
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <a href="new-state">Foo</a> 
        <a href="other-state">Hallo</a> 
        <div id="log"></div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.onpopstate()` should fire on the initial page load, which counts as a history traversal. See [this WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41372), which has been resolved in recent WebKit builds. (You code outputs HELLO as designed in Chrome 7.0.517.44, and presumably will do so in the next version of Safari.)

See also [my (invalid) Chrome bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040) for more discussion and links.

Comment: They made more changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688164/window-bind-popstate  This answer is no longer correct.