# HTML5 popstate event passed null

Tags: javascript, html, history, pushstate

I'm facing a strange issue where where popstate returns null, regardless, even if pushState has fired seven or eight times.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {

    console.log(event.state);

});
```

I have also tried:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        console.log(event.state);
};
```

But no luck.  I'm using Chrome.

Comment: According to the documentation ... "Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript)." ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Comment: Right, I should have clarified, I still get null even while using the browsers back or forward buttons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window bind POPSTATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688164/window-bind-popstate)

Comment: OK ... I also noticed that the `state` was sometimes empty; do you get anything with `console.log(event)`?

Comment: @OnlyMAJ This is not a duplicate.  I do not care whether this fires on initial load, I only want popstate to work when navigating using the browsers forward/back buttons.

Comment: @rfornal I do get something with event.  It shows PopStateEvent {state: null, clipboardData: undefined, path: NodeList[0], cancelBubble: false, returnValue: true…}

Comment: Not sure why this was associated with a question of a different issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was not correctly setting the pushState variable.